# Error writing Sec^2(x) -0.5 x in define function in C++

Tags: c++

Okay I'm trying to make a root finder calculator and right now I was testing it out trigonometric functions. Now I'm getting errors whenever a sec is involved prompting either a "sec has not been defined"

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxhNW.png)
Can someone explain to me whats wrong and how can I write "Sec^2(x)-0.5"

Comment: `^` doesn't do what you think it does!

Comment: Copy-paste text (especially code) *as text* into your questions. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Also, `2(x)` doesn't do what you want, it's actually not valid syntax. I recommend you invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn the basics (and that includes not using macros).

Comment: Why using macros? A short inline function would do the same and you are type-safe, can use variables, ... e.g.: `double g(double x) { x = sec(x); return x*x - .5; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C++ standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath#Trigonometric_functions) doesn't provide secant function, you have to define it yourself.

```
double sec(double x)
{
    return 1 / cos(x);
}
```

Also, `^2` does not mean "square" in C++, it's "bitwise XOR". You need to use `*` or `pow`:

```
sec(x) * sec(x) - 0.5;
pow(sec(x), 2) - 0.5;
```

And don't use macros, they are going to bite you. Functions are much easier to use and will always behave as you expect:

```
double g(double x)
{
    return sec(x) * sec(x) - 0.5;
}
```